# Can`t part disk because 'invalid token primary'

Tags: partition, parted

I`m trying to partition the external HDD on my raspberry, I am running Raspbian (debian). When I run the command;

```
mkpart primary ntfs 45%
```

It will say:
[image: invalid token primary]

But the help says:

[image: primary]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should partition the drive `/dev/sda` and not the partition `/dev/sda1`.

The message is not really helpful to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks, now it says End? What do I need to do now??

Comment: Are you sure you have some free space on that device? Have you run `parted /dev/sda`?

Comment: @Anthon I have a related question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231164/how-do-i-partition-a-centos-7-server-using-parted

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. The solution was to create partition with fdisk, than delete it, and use exactly the same parted command.
You could also try partprobe and than parted command it might work.