# how do I partition a CentOS 7 server using parted?

Tags: centos, terminal, partition, parted

I am planning to divide the largest partition on the hard drive of a CentOS 7 server into four smaller partitions using `parted`.  Three of the new partitions will be 300 GB each, and the fourth partition will take the remainder.  I have shown the `parted print` report for the drive below, followed by the syntax of the commands that I imagine using.  **How do I change the code below in order to properly partition the hard drive?**

Here is the result of the `print` report in `parted`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# parted
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-22D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16           EFI System Partition  boot
 2      211MB   735MB   524MB   ext4
 3      735MB   1938GB  1938GB  ext4
 4      1938GB  1992GB  53.7GB  ext4
 5      1992GB  2000GB  8187MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

So I imagine that the terminal commands are as simple as:

```
rm 3
mkpart    ext4    735MB    300GB
mkpart    ext4    300GB    600GB  
mkpart    ext4    600GB    900GB  
mkpart    ext4    900GB    1938GB
```

**How do I change the code above to correctly create the partitions?**

For reference, `fdisk -l` gives a slightly different picture of the drive as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      1435647    500M  Microsoft basic 
 3      1435648   3786041343    1.8T  Microsoft basic 
 4   3786041344   3890898943     50G  Microsoft basic 
 5   3890898944   3906889727    7.6G  Linux swap
```

---

**EDIT:**

---

I have been trying to use @Anthon's suggestions, but am getting different results.  The `fdisk -l` and `parted ... print` environment is slightly different now after re-installing CentOS, but the same basic concepts apply because this should be reproduceable.  When I type `select /dev/dm-1` all the existing partitions seem to become invisible to `parted`, but when I skip `select /dev/dm-1`, I get an error.  Here is the actual terminal record:

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt

#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      1435647    500M  Microsoft basic 
 3      1435648    105850879   49.8G  Microsoft basic 
 4    105850880    121841663    7.6G  Linux swap      

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-fb2eda94-fcff-4624-8b04-a9786845504a: 53.5 GB, 53458501632 bytes, 104411136 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-08f8bdb9-85bf-45ef-9519-3f38906c489a: 1938.0 GB, 1938005426176 bytes, 3785166848 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

[root@localhost ~]# df -T -h
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0      ext4       49G  1.1G   46G   3% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.8G  8.7M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2      ext4      477M  110M  338M  25% /boot
/dev/sda1      vfat      200M  9.8M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/dm-1      ext4      1.8T   77M  1.7T   1% /home

[root@localhost ~]# parted
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16           EFI System Partition  boot
 2      211MB   735MB   524MB   ext4
 3      735MB   54.2GB  53.5GB
 4      54.2GB  62.4GB  8187MB  linux-swap(v1)
 5      62.4GB  2000GB  1938GB

(parted) unit compact
(parted) select /dev/dm
Error: Could not stat device /dev/dm - No such file or directory.
Retry/Cancel? cancel                                                      
(parted) select /dev/dm-1                                                 
Using /dev/dm-1
(parted) rm 5
Error: Partition doesn't exist.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)
Disk /dev/dm-1: 1938GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  1938GB  1938GB  ext4

(parted) quit                                                             
[root@localhost ~]# parted
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16           EFI System Partition  boot
 2      211MB   735MB   524MB   ext4
 3      735MB   54.2GB  53.5GB
 4      54.2GB  62.4GB  8187MB  linux-swap(v1)
 5      62.4GB  2000GB  1938GB

(parted) unit compact                                                     
(parted) rm 5                                                             
Error: Partition(s) 5 on /dev/sda have been written, but we have been  
unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are  
in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You  
should reboot now before making further changes.
Ignore/Cancel?  ancel                                                     
(parted) quit
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

**So how do I actually partition this drive?**

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make a backup of at least partitions 1, 2 an 4 and the MBR. It is only 55Gb so that shouldn't take that long.

The `mkpart` command takes the filesystem type as an optional parameter after the required partition type:

```
mkpart PART-TYPE [FS-TYPE] START END     make a partition
```

and you seem to give the file system type (`ext4`) as the partition type. I normally don't bother to give the filesystem type, formatting the partition later on will take care of that.

I would do:

```
$ parted
unit compact    
select /dev/sda
rm 3
mkpart  " "    735MB    300GB
mkpart  " "    300GB    600GB  
mkpart  " "    600GB    900GB  
mkpart  " "    900GB    1938GB
```

The start-end numbers look OK to me.

The explicit selection of device `/dev/sda` might not be necessary if you only have one drive in your machine, which raises the question are you really running a server without any kind of raid? If you do you should have at least a full replacement device on which you can make a backup before attempting the above.

What is unclear is **why** you want to do this. Smaller partitions are less flexible and fill up more easily. Depending on what you want to achieve you should consider using LVM on top of the (undivided) partition. If you create one volume group with four logical volumes in it, you can create four filesystems as well, but much more easily allocate change their sizes.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to answer this.  The reason I need to make the partitions is that this is secure data with separate virtual machines for apps, data, etc.  Each partition will be encrypted separately, and the data vms will only be able to communicate with the app vms, thus providing a layer of protection of the data from malicious users.  The separate partition encryption will provided added protection against theft of the data.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are going to put VM discs in those partitions than you have other options for resizing, and LVM would just be extra overhead (negligible compared to the encryption). That looks like something that could work, but you would have to type your 3-4 passwords before you can use the partitions -> no automatic up-and-running after reboot.

Comment: Please see the **EDIT** to my OP documenting errors that I get when trying your method.  I had not actually tried your methods when I accepted the answer and commented, because I had to re-install CentOS.  Can you please help me find syntax that works in this situation?

Comment: @CodeMed dm-1 is a mounted partition on a loop device. you cannot partition that further. You should partition the main device and make each individual loop devices to encrypted drives. Your edit makes for a completely different question, you should turn that back and ask a different quesiton on why you can't partition a luks mounted partition.

Comment: I will happily create a separate question.  however, I am told that LUKS does not allow in-place encryption and thus LUKS encryption has to be done during the CentOS installation process.  If the answer to the new question is that I cannot partition a LUKS mounted partition, then I will be stuck in a loop myself.  Can you please shed light before I start creating too many looped questions?

Comment: @CodeMed I have had a LUKS partition set up after complete install for several years on a disc containing my /home filesystem I never set that up during install always afterwards

Comment: I set up LUKS encyption at install, and I chose Standard Partion instead of LVM due to your first comment above.  Someone on the other question is suggestion that LVM is what is needed.  I could re-install using LVM.  I just want to avoid running around in circles.  Are you willing to comment on the new question?  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231653/why-cant-i-partition-a-luks-mounted-partition

Comment: Do you further partition your LUKS partitions?  If so, how?  I am still getting the same error even after re-installing CentOS using LVM as the partition type.  A made an EDIT to the other posting (link in preceding comment) documenting it.