# why can't I partition a LUKS mounted partition?

Tags: centos, partition, luks, gparted, parted

A CentOS 7 server has to have LUKS encryption for everything but `/boot` and `/boot/efi`.  And the large LUKS encrypted remainder partition (1.8 TB) will then need to be partitioned further.  I was able to LUKS encrypt the required part of the hard drive during the CentOS 7 installation process, but now I am not able to create additional partitions within the large LUKS partition.  **How can I create partitions within the large (1.8 TB) LUKS-encrypted partition?**  Here is the actual terminal record of my attempts so far:

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt

#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      1435647    500M  Microsoft basic 
 3      1435648    105850879   49.8G  Microsoft basic 
 4    105850880    121841663    7.6G  Linux swap      

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-fb2eda94-fcff-4624-8b04-a9786845504a: 53.5 GB, 53458501632 bytes, 104411136 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-08f8bdb9-85bf-45ef-9519-3f38906c489a: 1938.0 GB, 1938005426176 bytes, 3785166848 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

[root@localhost ~]# df -T -h
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0      ext4       49G  1.1G   46G   3% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.8G  8.7M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2      ext4      477M  110M  338M  25% /boot
/dev/sda1      vfat      200M  9.8M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/dm-1      ext4      1.8T   77M  1.7T   1% /home

[root@localhost ~]# parted
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16           EFI System Partition  boot
 2      211MB   735MB   524MB   ext4
 3      735MB   54.2GB  53.5GB
 4      54.2GB  62.4GB  8187MB  linux-swap(v1)
 5      62.4GB  2000GB  1938GB

(parted) unit compact
(parted) select /dev/dm
Error: Could not stat device /dev/dm - No such file or directory.
Retry/Cancel? cancel                                                      
(parted) select /dev/dm-1                                                 
Using /dev/dm-1
(parted) rm 5
Error: Partition doesn't exist.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)
Disk /dev/dm-1: 1938GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  1938GB  1938GB  ext4

(parted) quit                                                             
[root@localhost ~]# parted
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16           EFI System Partition  boot
 2      211MB   735MB   524MB   ext4
 3      735MB   54.2GB  53.5GB
 4      54.2GB  62.4GB  8187MB  linux-swap(v1)
 5      62.4GB  2000GB  1938GB

(parted) unit compact                                                     
(parted) rm 5                                                             
Error: Partition(s) 5 on /dev/sda have been written, but we have been  
unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are  
in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You  
should reboot now before making further changes.
Ignore/Cancel?  cancel                        
(parted) quit
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

---

**EDIT:**

---

Per @TomHunt's suggestion, I re-installed CentOS 7 on the machine, **this time using `LVM`** as the partition type for all the relevant partitions, including the large 1.8 TB partition.  However, `parted` is still giving the same error when I try to `rm 3` to prepare to partition the 1.8 TB partition.  Here is the terminal log for my most recent attempt:

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt

#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      1435647    500M  Microsoft basic 
 3      1435648   3906914303    1.8T  Microsoft basic 

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-75fe4a52-a76f-4dfb-8cb9-da59ba955a55: 1999.6 GB, 1999602974720 bytes, 3905474560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 8187 MB, 8187281408 bytes, 15990784 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 1937.7 GB, 1937718116352 bytes, 3784605696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

[root@localhost ~]# df -T -h
Filesystem              Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root ext4       50G  836M   46G   2% /
devtmpfs                devtmpfs  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.8G  8.6M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2               xfs       494M  115M  379M  24% /boot
/dev/sda1               vfat      200M  9.8M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/centos-home ext4      1.8T   77M  1.7T   1% /home
[root@localhost ~]# parted
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16        EFI System Partition  boot
 2      211MB   735MB   524MB   xfs
 3      735MB   2000GB  2000GB

(parted) rm 3                                                             
Error: Partition(s) 3 on /dev/sda have been written, but we have been unable to inform
the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old
partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.
Ignore/Cancel? cancel                                                     
(parted) quit                                                             
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

**So how do I actually partition this drive?**

Comment: You probably want to use LVM here. Use the single large partition (I'm assuming that's the 50G one here) as a physical volume, making sure you LUKS-encrypt it first (add `/dev/dm-0` or whichever as the physical volume). Then you can create logical volumes for whatever you want, and they'll all automatically be encrypted by the LUKS layer below LVM.

Comment: @TomHunt  Please see the **EDIT** to my OP.  I set `LVM` as the partition type while re-installing CentOS, then repeated the steps, but `parted` is still giving me the same error.  What am I missing?

Comment: Okay, so you probably don't want to use `parted` here at all. Both LVM and LUKS live above the level of physical partitions; all you need is for the 2T space to be a single partition, which you have. If you had a spare disk, or were willing to do some manual messing around, you could migrate this system directly using `pvmove` (though you'd then have to make sure that the initrd supported opening the encrypted volume).

Comment: @TomHunt I need to make multiple partitions INSIDE the 1.8 TB partition.  This server requires multi-level encryption, with the whole disk encrypted, and then with each of the partitions within the 1.8 TB partition each having their own separate encryption.  So that someone stealing the hard drive would need to crack multiple levels of encryption before seeing real data.  Thus, keeping it as one partition as you suggest will not work in this case.

Comment: You're confused about the meaning of the word "partition". A physical partition is a device like `/dev/sda3`; you only need one of those. LVM sits on top of this physical partition (once you've encrypted it) and turns it into multiple logical volumes, which have names you give them. You can then encrypt those separately. But there's only one thing involved that's called a "partition".

Comment: @TomHunt  I need disk-level encryption and partition-level encryption for a web server that has highly sensitive data.  I have read that LUKS encryption can do both disk level encryption and partition level encryption.  However, when I researched disk level encryption, I was told that I have to leave `/boot` and `/boot/efi` unencrypted in order for the server to be able to boot up.  This is how I got to encrypting everything but those two partitions, and thus the current confusion.  How do I mix both disk-level encryption and partition-level encryption on a CentOS 7 web server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29468/discussion-between-tom-hunt-and-codemed).

Comment: @TomHunt, this isn't really the place to be asking, but can you explain what markup/steps you used to open a chat on this topic and migrate the existing comment thread over there? I expect there's some magic command I don't know.

Comment: @dubiousjim I clicked the "automatically migrate this discussion to chat" button which showed up after enough messages were posted.